# King Solomon's offering location

Tags: melachim-kings-book-of, mishkan-tabernacle, king-solomon, location

In [I Kings 3:4](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt09a03.htm#4), Shlomo goes to Gibeon to make a korban at the great bima. Rashi says that this great bima is the copper altar from the mishkan.

In verse 15, Shlomo is in Jerusalem and in the same sentence offers burnt offerings and peace offerings before the Ark.

Why are the ark and altar not in the same place?